# Arithmetic Overflow in mips

Tags: mips, integer-overflow

I am just started learning exception handler of MIPS instruction.

I need to make my program to have Arithmetic overflow exception so that i can test my exception handler.

I have two array A and B. Array A has hex number and Array B has integers.

How to make overflow by adding hex number and integer ?

The addition of which hex number and integer can cause overflow?

Comment: I'm not familiar with MIPS, but hex is just a representation of a number, not a datatype, so surely you're just adding two integers. If your integers are 32 bits, then any two numbers which add to more than `2^32-1` (i.e. `4294967295`) will produce an overflow.

Comment: Thank you Simon, i tried it already. I tried like this 0x1+4294967295. but I still don't get an overflow error. i get the answer 0x0.

Comment: Are you using `add` or `addi`? As far as I can see, [if you use signed instructions, you should get overflow exceptions](http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html).

Comment: i used "add". i should get overflow right?

Comment: The problem is probably that if you're using signed operations,  the largest (signed) integer is actually `2^31-1`. Try adding 1 to that.

Comment: Wow !!! It works. I got the overflow exception error. It look like i am the only one who is happy to get the error. LOL Thanks a lot Simon. You are a great help. :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [MIPS instruction reference](http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html), the only addition operations which can produce overflow exceptions are the signed addition instructions:

```
ADD
ADDI
```

MIPS integers are 32-bit, and since you'll be using signed integers, the maximum value is 2<sup>31</sup>-1 (aka 2147483647 or hex 7FFFFFFF). Thus any addition which results in a number larger than this should throw an exception, e.g if you try to add 1 to 2147483647:

```
# Load 2147483647 into $s1
LUI $s0, 32767
ORI $s1, $s0, 65535

# Add 1 to $s1 and store in $s2. This should produce an overflow exception
ADDI $s2, $s1, 1
```

Comment: How come is the maximum value (2^31) -1? Your range for an unsigned number is from 0 to (2^32) -1, using 32-bit integers!

Comment: Very good point @RoronoaZoro - I'm not sure why I wrote "*un*signed" - ADD and ADDI are signed operations (which I even mentioned at the top of the answer). I've removed the "un"!