# Does it affect the working of programs that how negative numbers are represented internally?

Tags: c++, binary, bit, internals, negative-number

I am not specific about any algorithm or program. But considering bit manipulation programs and other tasks that involves 2's complement or 1's complement etc., what if the negative numbers are represented (in memory or wherever) in a way opposite to the assumptions of the programmer. Does this scenario even occur? If yes, then how can it be handled.

Comment: It is very common that something works on a platform differently (your "etc.") than programmer assumed. Defective software will refuse to compile or fail tests. Defects are handled by programming non-defective code.

Comment: why specifically negative numbers? There are different ways to store positives too

Comment: somewhat related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70801443/why-is-signed-overflow-due-to-computation-still-undefined-behavior-in-c20

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does this scenario even occur?

Yes, before C++20 that is allowed and there have been architectures that don't use two's complement in the past. However since C++20 two's complement representation is mandated.

> If yes, then how can it be handled.

By not relying on operations with implementation-defined behavior or by asserting that your code may only be used on two's complement architectures.

Comment: This change is welcome but about 30 years too late IMHO.