# long integer is out of range negative product

Tags: c++, long-integer, long-long

I was trying to find product of some long long integer (0<=a[i]<=10^18)t. now how do i find that the product exeeds 10^18? does the product turn into negetive number (product<0)?

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    long long a[n],product=1;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>a[i];
    }
    sort(a,a+n);
    for(auto i:a){
        product*=i;
        if(i==0) break;
        if(product>1000000000000000000) {
            cout<<-1;
            return 0;
        }
    }
    cout<<product;
}
```

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) [Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard)

Comment: In short: Don't use so-called "competition" sites to learn C++. Invest in [some good C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) instead.

Comment: As for your problem, if you have input that exceeds the range of the standard integer types of C++, then you need to either come up with your own way of handling such numbers, or find a library which does it for you.

Comment: @Humanware Why `10^18` specifically ?

Comment: @Fareanor 10^9 and 10^18 are common limits in code competition sites because they're the largest power of 10 that fits in int32_t and int64_t

Comment: Note that, *mathematically*, you can express `a[i] * product < 10^18` as `a[i] < 10^18 / product`. Given the constraints on the data, you could also store them in an `unsigned` type, let it wrap around (in a defined way) and check if the result is less than the operands.

Comment: @phuclv I see. I would still use `std::numeric_limits<T>::max()` though :)

Comment: About the second question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70801443/why-is-signed-overflow-due-to-computation-still-undefined-behavior-in-c20

Answer (score 1):

If you are to check against potential overflow, I would advise you to rely on `std::numeric_limits<>::max()` (from the `<limits>` header) instead of a power of `10` (because the latter eliminates (a lot) of valid values).

Another advantage is portability. Indeed, in your code, you assume that `long long` is 8 bytes long which may not always be the case on another platform. Using `std::numeric_limits<>::max()` would guarantee to get the right maximum for the specified numeric type.

---

> *"Does the product turn into negative number ?"*

Actually, signed overflow is Undefined Behaviour so anything can happen. It may be negative, it may not, old legends say that you can even get demons flying out of your nose :D

In case of Undefined Behaviour, it's pointless to reason about the behaviour of the program, unless we look at the generated assembly code to see what will really happen.

> *"How do I find that the product doesn't overflow ?"*

In other words, the question is, how to check if `a * b > max` ? *(where `max` is  `std::numeric_limits<long long>::max()`)*.

Well, as written, you can't, because by definition, you cannot represent anything higher than `max` and evaluating `a*b` would be undefined behaviour anyway.

But the above test can be rewritten as `a > max / b` (with `b != 0`). We turned the multiplication into a division, and consequently the test is now evaluable without overflow.

To avoid clutter in your code, you could perform the test into a dedicated function. Such function might be defined as follows:

```
#include <concepts>
#include <limits>
#include <cmath>

template <std::integral T>
bool verify_product_range(T a, T b)
{
    return (!b || std::abs(a) <= std::numeric_limits<T>::max()/std::abs(b)); // Returns false if a*b overflows, true otherwise.
}
```

<sup>**Note:** For the above example, the validity range excludes `std::numeric_limits<T>::min()`. [See here](https://godbolt.org/z/68Y4dGGj6) for a more complete version (or below).</sup>

---

##### Edit

A more complete version of the above example (taking into account `std::numeric_limits<>::min()` as well in the validity range) might be:

```
template <std::integral T>
bool verify_product_range(T a, T b)
{
    if(!b || !a)
        return true; // zero is always valid

    if(a/b > 0) // If the product is positive
        return (std::abs(a) <= std::numeric_limits<T>::max()/std::abs(b));
    
    else // else (if the product is negative)
    {
        if(b < 0) std::swap(a, b);

        return (a >= std::numeric_limits<T>::min()/b);
    }
}
```

Comment: I wrote a `verify_verify_product_range`, [here](https://godbolt.org/z/obz6s9qPh).  **Hacker's Delight** (1e, section 2-12) discusses that this algorithm is not easy for product overflow (without resorting to a wider type, like I did — and that's cheating).

Comment: @Eljay Interesting, but it prevents any definition with the widest type available (since there are nothing wider at hand).

Answer (score 0):

In my code, I use function `isOverflow()` to check it. You can search and go through `std::numeric_limits<T>::max()`.

Additionally, since the first comments mentioned several questions about C++ practice, so I made some changes on your code for a better C++ coding habit and convention. I explained the reason by comments.

According to the suggestion of comments, I have removed VLA(Variable Length Array).

```cpp
#include <algorithm> // for std::sort
#include <iostream>  // for std::cin, std::cout, std::endl
#include <limits>    // for std::numeric_limits

bool isOverflow(long long a, long long b)
{
    if (a == 0 || b == 0)
    {
        return false; // No overflow can occur with zero operands
    }

    if (a > std::numeric_limits<long long>::max() / b)
    {
        return true; // Overflow detected
    }

    return false;
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    long long product = 1;

    while (n > 0)
    {
        long long val;
        std::cin >> val;

        if (val < 0) // Since you mentioned that integer >= 0
        {
            std::cout << "Negative number is not allowed! Please re-enter!\n";
        }
        else if (val == 0)
        {
            product = 0;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            if (isOverflow(product, val) == false)
            {
                product *= val;
                n--; // Count the number of valid input.
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "The product is overflowed" << std::endl;
                // Easier to understand than just print -1.
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }

    std::cout << "The product is " << product << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but your comment about `auto` is an non-sense. `auto` is a placeholder, that the compiler will deduce (if possible) and replace with the proper type. In other words `for(auto i : a)` **is replaced with** `for(int i : a)` (note the `const` is unnecessary since you take by value (i.e. copy)). It has nothing to do with the type size or whatever this comment is supposed to mean.

Comment: Moreover, you basically just rewrote the OP's code. It doesn't answer OP's question about overflow handling (well I recognize the question title is more explicit than the question itself :D).

Comment: I know your consideration. I have explained the reason is only for readability. I made these changes because the first comments mentioned several questions about c++ good practice,so I just give OP a reference.

Comment: I just realized that in _"is very short"_ you meant very short to type (to write) and not very short in size (memory) :D

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make myself clear. I will edit it.

Comment: Please consider dropping the VLA too, It's not standard C++. The OP could also (probably, the actual problem statement is missing) solve this *without* storing (and sorting) the numbers in a container.

Comment: Added a version without VLA.